# Search for an object in a List<Object>

Tags: c#, list

I have this `List` that contains instances of `Story` class:

```
List<Story> Stories = new List<Story>();

public class Story
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public double Height { get; set; }
    public double Elevation { get; set; }
}
```

Each of the instances in the List are unique:

```
Stories = {Story1, Story2, ...}
```

Now in another method I want to search for a specific `Story` in the `List` and and assign the whole object to a newly created object

```
Story st = Find a Story in the Stories that its Story.Id=="Story2"
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use LINQ with either method syntax:

```
Story st = Stories.Where(x => x.Id == "Story2").FirstOrDefault();
```

or query syntax:

```
Story st = (from story in Stories
              where story.Id.Equals("Story2")
              select story).FirstOrDefault();
```

You can use `Single()`, `First()`, `FirstOrDefault()`, `SingleOrDefault` at the end of the statement. Here is the differences between them.

- `First()` - throws if empty/not found, does not throw if duplicate
- `FirstOrDefault()` - returns default if empty/not found, does not throw if duplicate
- `Single()` - throws if empty/not found, throws if duplicate exists
- `SingleOrDefault()` - returns default if empty/not found, throws if duplicate exists

Comment: @Vahid No problem, I know. )

Comment: Thanks for the thorough answer.

Answer (score 1):

Since "Each of the instances in the List are unique"

```
Story st = Stories.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == "Story2");
```

Alternatively

```
Story st = Stories.Single(x=>x.Id == "Story2");
```

The difference is the first will return default if nothing found, the second will raise an exception in that case

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ:

```
var story = stories.Where((p) => p.Id == "Goldilocks").FirstOrDefault();
```